# Cannot start hardhat node when specifying networks in config (timeout error HH604)

Tags: hardhat

I'm new to hardhat and trying to specify forked as well as testnet networks in the config file. Using various samples from hardhat.org and various tutorials, I thought I had it nailed with the following:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      { version: "0.5.16" },
      { version: "0.6.6" },
      { version: "0.8.17" },
    ],
  },
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: "https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/c34565hsdfrdsTfuPip1_l24sddewe4ddB3wn",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Running `npx hardhat node`, with this config however, I always get an Error HH604 JSON-RPC timeout. Without the network part, i.e. with

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      { version: "0.5.16" },
      { version: "0.6.6" },
      { version: "0.8.17" },
    ],
  },
};
```

Tried other network configurations as well, including copy paste from hardhat.org, but can't make it work.

What is strange as well, is that I can see hardhat connecting to the provider (alchemy) with a whole bunch of getTransactionCount requests.

Any help how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue in the end: it seems that hardhat does not work well together with a VPN. Had to use split tunnelling in the VPN (or shut it down completely) to make it work.